# Control width transformation ( CSS )

Tags: css

I have some cards in a div and want them to change width on hover, but have two issues whith it:

1. I want to use transition , but the cards that are not hovered do transition after hovered card ends one. I want do it simultaneously.
2. How to change origin for 3rd and 4th card, so they change their width from right to left?

here is my code

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cardBox {
  width: 800px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 201, 202);
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%
}

.card:hover {
  width: 450px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.card:hover~ :not(:hover) {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}

.card span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgb(41, 40, 40);
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardBox">
  <div class="card">
    <!-- <img src="/1.jpg" alt=""> -->
    <span>CSS</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- <img src="/3.jpg" alt=""> -->
    <span>image</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- <img src="/2.jpg" alt=""> -->
    <span>hover</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- <img src="/4.jpg" alt=""> -->
    <span>effect</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cardBox {
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 201, 202);
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.card:hover {
  width: 450px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  flex: 4;
}

.card:hover~ :not(:hover) {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}

.card span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgb(41, 40, 40);
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardBox">
  <div class="card">
    <!-- <img src="/1.jpg" alt=""> -->
    <span>CSS</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- <img src="/3.jpg" alt=""> -->
    <span>image</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- <img src="/2.jpg" alt=""> -->
    <span>hover</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- <img src="/4.jpg" alt=""> -->
    <span>effect</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was grid display and wrong css selector (`.card:hover~ :not(:hover)`). Also, use transition in the selector not in :hover selector.

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cardBox {
  width: 800px;
  /* display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); */
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 201, 202);
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* width: 100% */
  width: 25%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.card:hover {
  width: 450px;
  /* transition: all 1s ease; */
}

/* .card:hover~ :not(:hover) {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
} */

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}

.card span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgb(41, 40, 40);
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardBox">
  <div class="card">
    <!-- <img src="/1.jpg" alt=""> -->
    <span>CSS</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- <img src="/3.jpg" alt=""> -->
    <span>image</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- <img src="/2.jpg" alt=""> -->
    <span>hover</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- <img src="/4.jpg" alt=""> -->
    <span>effect</span>
  </div>
</div>
```